# ld: duplicate symbol - caused by const

Tags: objective-c, c, constants, linker-errors, c-preprocessor

I was defining a NSString to use as error domain in NSError and was copying how ASIHttpRequest was doing there's.

```
NSString* const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";
```

I put the const in its own .h file
    //  FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants.h

```
#ifndef FirePlayer_FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants_h
#define FirePlayer_FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants_h

NSString* const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";

#endif
```

but when I included it in more than one .m

```
SomeFile.m

#import "FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants.h"

SomeOtherFile.m

#import "FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants.h"
```

I got linker error 'duplicate symbol'

```
ld: duplicate symbol _FPServerAPIErrorDomain in SomeFile.o and ....SomeOtherFile.o for architecture armv7
```

so I change the const to #define and it worked ok.

```
//  FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants.h

#ifndef FirePlayer_FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants_h
#define FirePlayer_FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants_h


//THIS WAS TRIGGERING link errors
//NSString* const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";
//working OK
#define FPServerAPIErrorDomain @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain"

#endif
```

But is there a way to get the const in global space not to throw 'duplicate symbol'?

Comment: if you leave out the include file magic, is your question the same as: "can I do **const int i=42;** twice in the same source/binary?

Comment: yes but also 'how do you NOT use #defines and use const in global space'? is it possible? is it preferred? #define works but why have consts then? Im a java person moved into Obj-c I havent qualified in voodoo 101 yet

Comment: You haven't copied what ASIHttpRequest is doing at all. Go back and look again.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In your header file you want:

```
extern NSString *const FPServerAPIErrorDomain;
```

and then in an implementation file (so probably you want a `FPServerAPICoordinatorConstants.m`) you will want:

```
NSString *const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";
```

Then you can import the header into multiple file and not get duplicate symbol errors.

[By the way, you don't need the `#ifndef` guards if you're using `#import`.]

Comment: ha! apple put the ifndef in :) when I added header file from templates

Comment: That's probably because you added from a "C header" template. That will have them in by default as you'll want them if you use C-style `#include`s. But you're using Objective-C-style `#import`s. So get rid of the guards.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Save time for me.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to instantiate the same (global) variable twice in the same namespace (, without getting an error).

Comment: is there any advantage of using

    //NSString* const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";

over

    #define FPServerAPIErrorDomain @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain"

Answer (score 1):

Each symbol should only be defined once; that is, it should only be defined in one m file. By putting the definition in a header file, it gets defined in each m file that includes that header.

Define it in one of your m files (whichever is most relevant), and change what you have in the header to a declaration (using the extern keyword).

The definition makes space for the data; the declaration simply tells the compiler that there is a definition somewhere else. So every m file that uses the constant needs to have a declaration, but only one m file should have the definition.

Comment: is there any advantage of using

    //NSString* const FPServerAPIErrorDomain = @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain";

over

    #define FPServerAPIErrorDomain @"FPServerAPIErrorDomain"